# CSS Grid: How to Make Section Content Escape Container on One Side While Respecting Max-Width

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm working on a layout where I need a section element to break out of its container on one side to extend full-width, but on the other side, it should respect the max-width of its parent. I'm struggling to find a CSS solution that allows this behavior. I want the .full-width-split-screen section to have an accent div that breaks out of the max-width on the left side while the image on the right should stay within the bounds of the max-width. The .max-width-container should be centered with max-width applied. The mx-auto is a utility class I'm using to center the content. Can someone help me figure out the CSS needed to achieve this layout? The solution should be responsive and not require JavaScript.

Also is there any more robust solution for escaping max-width container? The most important thing is to respect margins and paddings as max-width does in the max-width-container. Both of this elements should have same margins.

On smaller screens it's working okay, but if we will check this out on 1920x1080 screen, then the margins are off.

```css
:root {
  --wrapper-padding-inline: 1rem;
  --wrapper-max-width: 50rem;
  --section-padding-block: 3rem;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: system-ui;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  line-height: 1.7;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

h1 {
  font-size: clamp(3rem, 10vw, 5rem);
  line-height: 1;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

section {
  padding-block: var(--section-padding-block);
}

.accent {
  background-color: var(--clr-accent);
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: var(--wrapper-max-width);
  margin-inline: auto;
  padding-inline: var(--wrapper-padding-inline);
}

.full-width-split-screen {
  padding-block: 0;
}

.full-width-split-screen > :not(img) {
  padding-block: var(--section-padding-block);
  padding-inline: var(--wrapper-padding-inline);
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .full-width-split-screen {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns:
      minmax(var(--wrapper-padding-inline), 1fr)
      minmax(0, calc(var(--wrapper-max-width) / 2))
      minmax(0, calc(var(--wrapper-max-width) / 2))
      minmax(var(--wrapper-padding-inline), 1fr);

    position: relative;
  }

  .full-width-split-screen > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }

  .full-width-split-screen > img:last-child {
    grid-column: 3 / -1;
  }

  .full-width-split-screen > :not(img) {
    display: grid;
    align-content: center;
    justify-items: start;
  }

  .full-width-split-screen > :not(img):first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
  }

  .full-width-split-screen > :not(img)::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    background: inherit;
  }

  .full-width-split-screen > :not(img):first-child::before {
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
  }
}

.max-width-container{
  max-width: 1188px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  padding: 24px;
}

.mx-auto{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Full-width on one side only</h1>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="full-width-split-screen">
  <div class="accent">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit officiis dolores vitae sed libero ipsa. Aut, eos accusantium, quas at laborum tempore ab quidem eum exercitationem odit excepturi incidunt iste.</p>
    <p>Deleniti voluptates harum nemo eos deserunt? Cum quos blanditiis dignissimos facilis , pariatur vel nostrum consectetur nesciunt in numquam.</p>
  </div>
  <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1684139517679-032b7213ad2e?q=80&w=2128&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D' alt=''>
</section>
<section class="max-width-container mx-auto">
    <p>Deleniti voluptates harum nemo eos deserunt? Cum quos blanditiis dignissimos facilis , pariatur vel nostrum consectetur nesciunt in numquam.</p>
  </div>
  <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1684139517679-032b7213ad2e?q=80&w=2128&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D' alt=''>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code from Kevin Powell.
[Codepen by Kevin Powell](https://codepen.io/kevinpowell/pen/ExrZrrw)
He uses grid with some cool things. I've built on top of that.

You can do:

```css
    .full-left {
        grid-column: full-width-start / content-end;
    }

    .full-right {
        grid-column: content-start / full-width-end;
    }
```

I also made this one:

```css
    .content-cols {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        gap: 1rem;
        grid-column: content;
    }
```

In there you can have elements side by side. But then If you want the image to flow to the right. Also add the class full-right to the same div as .content-cols.

So if you combine those you will get the effect you want.
I am useing scss, but here is my grid file.

```css
@mixin content-grid-setup(){
    --padding-inline: 1rem;
    --content-max-width: clamp(300px, 80vw, 1500px);
    --breakout-max-width: 2000px;
    --breakout-size: calc((var(--breakout-max-width) - var(--content-max-width)) / 2);
    display: grid;

    grid-template-columns:
    [full-width-start] minmax(var(--padding-inline), 1fr)
    [breakout-start] minmax(0, var(--breakout-size))
    [content-start] min(100% - (var(--padding-inline) * 2),var(--content-max-width))
    [content-end] minmax(0, var(--breakout-size)) 
    [breakout-end] minmax(var(--padding-inline), 1fr)
    [full-width-end];
}

@mixin full-width(){
    grid-column: full-width;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: inherit;
}

.content-grid {
    @include content-grid-setup();

    & {
        .content-cols {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 23vw 1fr;
            gap: 1rem;
            grid-column: content;
        }

        .full-width {
            @include full-width();
        }

        .content {
            grid-column: content;
        }

        .breakout {
            grid-column: breakout;
        }

        .full-left {
            grid-column: full-width-start / content-end;
        }

        .full-right {
            grid-column: content-start / full-width-end;
        }

        .breakout-left {
            grid-column: breakout-start / content-end;

            @include respond-to(lg) {
                grid-column: breakout-start / breakout-end;
            }
        }

        .breakout-right {
            grid-column: content-start / breakout-end;

            @include respond-to(lg) {
                grid-column: breakout-start / breakout-end;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have the cols set to have a kinda 40%, 60%, then for mobile. The container that has .content-cols, i set the following:

```css
grid-column: full-width;
gap: 0;
@include content-grid-setup();
```